# Android : filter many CAN IDs when monitoring CAN Data with ELM 327 throught Bluetooth

Tags: android, filter, bluetooth, can-bus, elm327

I am developping an Android app which will display CAN data using an ELM 327 in Bluetooth. Following the [ELM 327 Datasheet](http://elmelectronics.com/DSheets/ELM327DS.pdf), I can filter the received data by sending AT CRA hhh (hhh = CAN ID) before monitoring with AT MA.
My objective is to display data from specific CAN IDs (for example 7A2, 250, 420...).
I try to send many AT CRA hhh commands but just the last one is used by ELM.
My question is: **how can I set many CAN ID filters to the ELM327?**

The ELM also accepts CAN filter and a maks commands with AT CF and AT CM, is it the solution?

Answer (score 1):

CRA hhh is a convenient way to set easily a mask and a filter allowing to receive messages with a single CAN ID.

For example,

```
AT CRA 123
```

is equivalent to

```
AT CF 123
AT CM 7FF
```

So, yes, you are right, to receive a list of specific CAN IDs, you have to use the AT CF and AT CM commands and forge a specific (filter,mask) pair according to your needs.

Comment: Assume I want to filter a specific CAN ID 123, can you tell me how to do that? I have used AT CRA 123 and AT MA together, but the result shows all can messages are displayed....

Comment: I want to filter (receive)  CAN IDs 0x12A ans 0x174 (for example)- could you please give an example how to achieve that in ELM327?